# Carregar Página com Swipebox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero que ao abrir a página abra um Swipebox com uma imagem.

http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#try

Eu fiz assim:

### jQuery

```
    if($('.swipebox')[0]){
        $('.swipebox')[0].click();
    }

    // Swipe Box
    $('.swipebox').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.swipebox([
            { href: urlBase + '/imagem.jpg', title:'Safe' }
        ]);
    });
```

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="swipebox"></a>
```

Ao invés de ele abrir o Swipebox com a imagem, abre em outra página.
Mas se eu vou no Console do Chrome e digito:

`$('.swipebox').click();`, abre certo.

### Debug

Fiz isso qui e não funciona !

```
$('#open-swipebox').click();    

$('#open-swipebox').click(function (){
    console.log('das');
});

<a href="#" id="open-swipebox"></a>
```

Comment: Você quer que quando abra a página, automaticamente de um trigger no teu link?

Comment: Exatamente. Um `trigger`. Mas que já tentei e não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No load da página você emula o click no teu link:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.swipebox').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.swipebox([
        { href: urlBase + '/imagem.jpg', title:'Safe' }
    ]);
  });

  $('.swipebox').trigger('click');
});
```

No entanto, dessa maneira, irá ativar o evento para todos os itens que tenham essa classe, acho que seria melhor utilizar um id para o link.

```
<a href="#" class="swipebox" id="meuLink"></a>
```

E para emular o click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#meuLink').trigger('click');
});
```

**Complemento para a resposta**

> O evento **click** está sendo chamado antes da declaração, basta chamar o evento `$('.swipebox').click()` antes de atribuir o novo comportamento para o link/classe;

Comment: Algo bobo, mas tentou declarar o click antes de invocá-lo?

Comment: Como assim declarar ?

Comment: Fiz um simples debug e não funciona. Está dentro do ready.

Comment: Tenta inverter, da uma olhada como fiz na resposta (alterei agora). Tabém usei teu exemplo no fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PetrusStarken/9of7h7kc/

Comment: Nossa, velho. Era a inversão. Estava chamando o `trigger` antes da declaração da função. Foi noobisse isso. Valeu.

Comment: Também descobri isso agora, vou alterar a resposta pra ficar claro o que era.